# Why only async-safe functions should be called from a signal handler?

Tags: signals, sigaction, async-safe

I understand that, from a signal handler function `sigaction()` I should only call those functions that are "async-safe". But why is so?

Answer (score 1):

Calling an unsafe function may lead to undefined behavior.

The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7 (POSIX.1-2008), in its treatment of ["Signal Concepts"](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03), says:

> *[W]hen a signal interrupts an unsafe function ... and the signal-catching function calls an unsafe function, the behavior is undefined.*

As to *why* unsafe functions are unsafe, there may be many reasons in a given implementation.

However, a previous version of the standard, Issue 6 (POSIX.1-2004), hints at one possible reason on some implementations.  That version describes async-signal-safe functions as [*"either reentrant or non-interruptible by signals"*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_04.html#tag_02_04_03).  So, consider a function which relies on static data to keep state but is interrupted *by itself* midway through its execution — can that data be trusted once control returns to the interrupted function?